# Is there a way to get mongoose findById functions to behave consistently for deleted and non existent ids?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

`Mongoose.findById` (and `findByIdAndUpdate`, etc.) seem to behave differently when given:

1. **An id that never existed**: throws a CastError because in the process mongoose fails to cast the string given to an ObjectId.
2. **An Id that existed but was deleted**: just silently returns null.

It's messing with my code structure to check for the two things, while in my view, they're both the same case.

Example:

```
module.exports.findTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.locals.todo = await Todo.findById(req.params.id);
    // Handle deleted documents. THIS CHECK SHOULDN'T BE NECESSARY
    if (!res.locals.todo) {
      throw new NotFoundError('id');
    }
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    // Handling CastError later here
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you give examples of ids that are failing to cast? It sounds like `params.id` isn't a valid mongo id.

Comment: @willis it's just a string `"5d188a4dc6a44e1b039183b3"` corresponding to a Todo document that was deleted.

Comment: @willis actually yes case 1 only happens when the params.id field isn't a valid mongo id.